# dbt jinja returning the results of a query

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am trying to model the following situation:

- given some query, return multi-column result-set (e.g. `run_query` or `db_utils.get_query_results_as_dict`
- iterate over in a case/statment

for exmaple:

```
{% set conditions = dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict("select comment, criteria from " 
~ ref('the_model') %}

...
select case
{% for condition in conditions %}
when {{ condition["criteria"] }}
then {{ condition["comment"] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Have not been able to get this to work, any guidance appreciated.

Some ideas I tried:

- get_column_values x2 and zipping them into a new list of tuples. `zip not recognised`
- get the count(*) from `the_model` then trying to iterate over the range - ran into issues with types
- various `for` conditions `{% for k, v in conditions.items() %}`

Comment: What error do you see with the for loop condition the way you have it in the example you shared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to self resolve with the following:

```
{% set conditions = dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict("select criteria, comment from " ~ ref('reference_data') ~ " order by sequence desc") %}

with main as (
    select * from {{ ref('my_other_model') }}
),

-- [NEEDS_REVIEW] there's probably a cleaner way to do this iteration - however it's interpolated result. Could do with the zip function.
comments as (
    select
        *,
        case
            {# {{- log(conditions, info=True) -}} #}
            {%- for comment in conditions.COMMENT -%}
            when {{ conditions.CRITERIA[loop.index0] }}
            then '{{ comment }}'
            {% endfor %}
        end as comment

        from main
)

select * from comments
```

The gotchas:

- this was on snowflake, so the keys returned by the function will be up-cased as that is how I loaded the data.
- Using the `loop.index0` to get the current iteration of the loop and index into the other collection of tuples (in this case `CRITERIA`).
- i added a `SEQUENCE` key to my reference data just to ensure consistent rendering by using that to order. The criteria do overlap a-little bit so this was important.